# How to send timestamp in Handler class?

Tags: android

I have created a handler inside which I have parsed timestamp but i am getting an error as

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I think this is because of the textview which I have defined in xml I don't have idea of how to put textview then can. Can anybody help why I am getting this error as I have placed textview inside run() only

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                notificationDialog();
                break;
        }
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void notificationDialog() {
        mHandler=new Handler();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss");
                    String format = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

                    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.date);
                    textView.setText(format);

            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

XML file

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/button"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text = "Click"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For such simple code, why are you using a `Thread`?

Comment: I want to send this periodically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the UI from a different Thread. Android offers several ways to communicate a change to the UI Thread:

from https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads

> To fix this problem, Android offers several ways to access the UI thread from other threads. Here is a list of methods that can help:
>
> Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
>
> View.post(Runnable)
>
> View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)

A quick approach to accomplish what you are trying would be to use Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable).

```
private void notificationDialog() {
        Handler mHandler=new Handler();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss");
                final String format = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.date);
                        textView.setText(format);     
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }
```

The variable `format` needs to be declared as final to be able to be used in the inner Runnable.
We create a new runnable and tell the Activity to run it in the UiThread.

For more complicated scenarios you can use the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class.